# server freezes when handling large messages in simple server c++

Tags: c++

I have a client and server running, and it seems to run great, until I either a really large message, or a partial message. In either of those events it freezes. The buffer is set to 1024, but changing it doesn't seem to affect the message at all. I've copied the getRequest function where it freezes below.

If anyone knows why it freezes or how to deal with large and partial messages, that would be great, thanks.
It freezes on the line int nread = (client, buf_,1024,0); Any solutions?

```
    cout << "entered get request while loop" << endl;
    int nread = recv(client,buf_,1024,0);
    cout << "number read: " << nread << endl;






string
Server::get_request(int client) {
    cout << "getting request" << endl;
    string request = "";
    // read until we get a newline
    while (cache.find("\n") == string::npos) {
        cout << "entered get request while loop" << endl;
        int nread = recv(client,buf_,1024,0);
        if (nread < 0) {
            if (errno == EINTR)
                // the socket call was interrupted -- try again
                continue;
            else
                // an error occurred, so break out
                return "";
        } else if (nread == 0) {
            // the socket is closed
            return "";
        }
        // be sure to use append in case we have binary data
        cache.append(buf_,nread);
        cout << "cache: " << cache << " : " << endl;
    }

    int position = cache.find("\n");

    if (position == -1){
        request = cache;
        cache = "";
    }
    else{
    cout << "Cache position: " << position << endl;
    request = cache.substr(0,position+1);
        cache.erase(0,position+1);
    }
    cout << "request: " << request << " : " << endl;
    return request;
}
```

This is the full server.cc file

```
#include "server.h"
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>


Server::Server(int port) {
    // setup variables
    port_ = port;
    buflen_ = 1024;
    buf_ = new char[buflen_+1];
//    cache = "";
}

Server::~Server() {
    delete[] buf_;
    users.clear();
}





void
Server::run() {
    // create and run the server
    create();
    serve();
}

void
Server::create() {
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;

    // setup socket address structure
    memset(&server_addr,0,sizeof(server_addr));
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(port_);
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    // create socket
    server_ = socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if (!server_) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(-1);
    }

    // set socket to immediately reuse port when the application closes
    int reuse = 1;
    if (setsockopt(server_, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuse, sizeof(reuse)) < 0) {
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(-1);
    }

    // call bind to associate the socket with our local address and
    // port
    if (bind(server_,(const struct sockaddr *)&server_addr,sizeof(server_addr)) < 0) {
        perror("bind");
        exit(-1);
    }

    // convert the socket to listen for incoming connections
    if (listen(server_,SOMAXCONN) < 0) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(-1);
    }
}

void
Server::close_socket() {
    close(server_);
}

void
Server::serve() {
    // setup client
    int client;
    struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
    socklen_t clientlen = sizeof(client_addr);

      // accept clients
    while ((client = accept(server_,(struct sockaddr *)&client_addr,&clientlen)) > 0) {

        handle(client);
    }
    close_socket();
}



Server::Message Server::parse_request(string request){
    stringstream ss;
    istringstream istr(request);
    Message message;
    message.needed = false;
    message.valid = true;
    message.user = "";
    message.index = -1;
//    istream_iterator<string> be
    istr >> message.command;
    //message.command = ss.str();
    cout << "got command:" << message.command << ":" << endl;
    if(message.command == "put")
    {
        istr >> message.user;
        //ss << istr;
        istr >> message.subject;
        istr >> message.length;
        cout << "message.length = " << message.length <<endl;
        message.needed = false;
    }
    else if (message.command == "list"){
        istr >> message.user;
        message.needed = false;
        message.length = 0;
    }
    else if (message.command == "get"){
        istr >> message.user;
        istr >> message.index;
        message.needed = false;
        message.length = 0;
    }
    else if (message.command == "reset"){
        message.needed = false;
        message.length = 0;
    }
    else{
        cout << "I don't recognize that request.";
        message.valid = false;
    }
    return message;

}

void Server::get_value(int client, Message message){
    //call recv until all bytes needed are recieved

    while(message.needed){
        int nread = recv(client,buf_,1024,0);
        if (nread < 0) {
            if (errno == EINTR)
                // the socket call was interrupted -- try again
                continue;
            else
                // an error occurred, so break out
                return;
        } else if (nread == 0) {
            // the socket is closed
            return;
        }
        cache.append(buf_,nread);
        cout << "cache length " << cache.size();

        if(message.length <= cache.size()){
            cout << "Message value " << message.value;
            cout << "cache length " << cache.size();
            message.needed = false;
            message.value = cache.substr(0,message.length);
            cache.erase(0,message.length);
            cout << "Message value " << message.value;
            cout << "cache length " << cache.size();
        }
    }

}



string
Server::get_request(int client) {
    cout << "getting request" << endl;
    string request = "";
    // read until we get a newline
    while (cache.find("\n") == string::npos) {
        cout << "entered get request while loop" << endl;
        int nread = recv(client,buf_,1024,0);
        if (nread < 0) {
            if (errno == EINTR)
                // the socket call was interrupted -- try again
                continue;
            else
                // an error occurred, so break out
                return "";
        } else if (nread == 0) {
            // the socket is closed
            return "";
        }
        // be sure to use append in case we have binary data
        cache.append(buf_,nread);
        cout << "cache: " << cache << " : " << endl;
    }

    int position = cache.find("\n");
//    int position = 0;
//    while (cache.find("/n") == string::npos)
//    {
//        position++;
//    }

    if (position == -1){
        request = cache;
        cache = "";
    }
    else{
    cout << "Cache position: " << position << endl;
    request = cache.substr(0,position+1);
        cache.erase(0,position+1);
    }
    cout << "request: " << request << " : " << endl;
    // a better server would cut off anything after the newline and
    // save it in a cache
    return request;
}




bool Server::send_response(int client, string response) {

        // prepare to send response
    cout << "sending response:" << response << ":" << endl;
    const char* ptr = response.c_str();
    int nleft = response.length();
    int nwritten;
    // loop to be sure it is all sent
    while (nleft) {
        if ((nwritten = send(client, ptr, nleft, 0)) < 0) {
            if (errno == EINTR) {
                // the socket call was interrupted -- try again
                continue;
            } else {
                // an error occurred, so break out
                perror("write");
                return false;
            }
        } else if (nwritten == 0) {
            // the socket is closed
            return false;
        }
        nleft -= nwritten;
        ptr += nwritten;

        cout << "number written: " << nwritten << endl;
    }
    cout << "finished sending response " << endl;
    return true;

}

bool Server::handle_response(int client, Message message) {
    cout << "handling response" << endl;
    bool success = false;
         if(message.command == "put"){ 
             if(message.length == 0){
                 return false;
             }
             message.value = cache.substr(0,message.length);
             cache.erase(0,message.length);
             if(subjects.count(message.user) == 0){
                vector<string> userSubjects;
                subjects[message.user] = userSubjects; 
             }
            subjects[message.user].push_back(message.subject);
             if(users.count(message.user) == 0){
                vector<Message> messages;
                users[message.user] = messages;
             }
             users[message.user].push_back(message);
//            users.insert(message.user, message.subject);
             cout << "sending response to client" << endl;
            success = send_response(client, "OK\n");
         }
        else if("list" == message.command){ 
             if(message.user == ""){
                 return false;
             }
            vector<string> currentSubjects = subjects[message.user];
            cout << "subjects for message.user: " << message.user << endl;
            stringstream sstream;
            sstream << "list " << currentSubjects.size()  << "\n";
            //success = send_response(client, sstream.str());
//            if(success == false){
//                return false;
//            }
//            cout << "client sent user" << endl;
            for (int i=0; i<currentSubjects.size(); i++){
//                stringstream sstm;
                sstream << (i+1) << " " << currentSubjects[i] << "\n";

            }
            success = send_response(client, sstream.str());
            if(success == false){
                return false;
            }
           // success = true;
            cout << "message list sent successfully" << endl;

        }
        else if (message.command ==  "get"){ 
            if(message.index == -1){
                 return false;
             }
            if(message.user == ""){
                 return false;
             }
            vector<Message> currentMessages = users[message.user];
            if(message.index > currentMessages.size()){
                return false;
            }
            stringstream sstm;
            for (int i=0; i<currentMessages.size(); i++){
                if ((i+1) == message.index){
                    sstm << "message " << currentMessages[i].subject << " " << currentMessages[i].length << "\n" << currentMessages[i].value;
                    cout << "message.value = " << currentMessages[i].value << endl;

                }
            }
            cout << "message to send " << sstm.str() << endl;
             success = send_response(client, sstm.str());
                    if(success == false){
                        return false;
                    }
                   //     success = true;

        }

        else if (message.command ==  "reset"){
            users.clear();
            subjects.clear();
            success = send_response(client, "OK\n");
                      //  success = true;

        }
        else {
            debug = true;
            if (debug == true){
                cout << "Debug message: " << "No valid command found in handle" << endl;
            }       
        }
    return success;
}






void
Server::handle(int client) {
    // loop to handle all requests
    while (1) {
        // get a request
        cout << "looking for new request" << endl;
        string request = get_request(client);
        cout << "request = " << request << endl;
        // break if client is done or an error occurred
        if (request.empty()) {
            cout << "empty request" << endl;
            break;
        }
        cout << "request:" << request << ":" << endl;
        //parse
        Message message = parse_request(request);
        cout << "finished parsing" << endl;
        if(message.valid == false){
            cout << "invalid message" << endl;
            send_response(client, "error unrecognized command\n");
            cout << "cache after break from bad command: " << cache << endl;
            continue;   
        }

        if(message.length > cache.size()){
            message.needed = true;
            cout << "message length greater than cache size" << endl;
            cout << "cache.size = " << cache.size() << endl;
        }

        if(message.needed){
            get_value(client, message); 
        }

        // handle message
        bool success = handle_response(client, message);
        cout << "finished handling response" << endl;
        cout << "cache after handle: " << cache << " : " << endl;
        // break if an error occurred
        if (!success) {
            cout << "error handling request" << endl;
            send_response(client, "error handling request\n");
            continue;
        }
        cout << "end of request" << endl;
    }
    close(client);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible your `getRequest` is being called from more than  one thread?

Comment: No, I haven't added multiple threads yet. I need to make sure it works without first. Thanks though.

Comment: You need to show us exactly what `buf_` is -- where it's declared, etc.  If it's `buf[1024]`, then that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Server::Server(int port) {
    port_ = port;
    buflen_ = 1024;
    buf_ = new char[buflen_+1];
}

Comment: So this instance of `Server` you created -- is it being passed around by value?  And does it have a destructor that `delete[]`s the buffer?  See the conundrum you get yourself into by using `new[ ]` like that?  I smell a violation of the "rule of 3" for some reason.

Comment: Be good if you added a `cout` reporting the `nread` value, and posted the last few messages to `cout` before it freezes.  Not important, but `buf_` should be local to the function: (I trust it's not `static` and shared by multiple Server objects).

Comment: I just added the rest of the server.cc file, but I think I know the line that it freezes on, I just don't know why. I added them at the top of the question.

Comment: When it freezes, are you sure it isn't just sitting at `recv` waiting for more data? Use debugger or add debug prints to check.

Comment: You added code, but the most important part, the creation of the `Server` object is not shown and how this object is being used / passed around / stored, etc..  If the compiler created and destroyed temporary `Server` objects, then your `buffer` will become invalidated, so showing *how* you're creating and using `Server` is important.  Also, you used the wrong form of `delete` in your destructor (it should be `delete[ ]`, not just `delete`.

Comment: "Freezing" on `int nread = (client, buf_,1024,0);` suggests the client hasn't sent the rest of the line... you should be checking your client code.  And just make `char buf_[1024];` a function-local variable.

Comment: I don't have access to an IDE with a debugger (which honestly makes this a lot harder). How do I add a debug print within that line to see if recv is active or not? I was under the impression it would simply loop if nothing was received. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with c++ as much, and not using python or other libraries is new to me.

Comment: In the main function it calls     Server server = Server(port);
    server.debug = debug;
    server.run();   The buf_ and buflen are private members of server stored in server.h                          Also, I fixed the destructor, thanks.